# valgrind memory access error when accessing result of string::c_str()

Tags: c++, pointers, valgrind, stdstring

So I was writing some networking code when I ran into the strangest memory issue and I cant properly sort out what might be going on here. I am wondering if there might be some sort of implication in `c_str()` that I am not properly observing.

So here is the code with the error in it. (There is also a freeing error but I made this function as just a pet project).

```
#include <netdb.h>       // for AF_UNSPEC, AF_INET, AF_INET6
#include <stdint.h>      // for uint16_t, etc.
#include <sys/types.h>   // for AF_UNSPEC, AF_INET, AF_INET6
#include <sys/socket.h>  // for AF_UNSPEC, AF_INET, AF_INET6
#include <string>        // for std::strin
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    uint16_t port = 2098;


    struct addrinfo hints;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET6;       // IPv6 (also handles IPv4 clients)
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;  // stream
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;      // use wildcard "INADDR_ANY"
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;  // tcp protocol
    hints.ai_canonname = nullptr;
    hints.ai_addr = nullptr;
    hints.ai_next = nullptr;

    const char* port_num = (std::to_string(port)).c_str();

    struct addrinfo *result;
    int res = getaddrinfo(nullptr, port_num, &hints, &result);

    printf("HI\n");
}
```

If you valgrind the resulting binary you get:

```
==45919== Invalid read of size 1
==45919==    at 0x573BA5C: getaddrinfo (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==45919==    by 0x400C95: main (in /homes/iws/kieruc/Coding/a.out)
==45919==  Address 0x5a22058 is 24 bytes inside a block of size 29 free'd
==45919==    at 0x4C2B16D: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:576)
==45919==    by 0x4EF3B62: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==45919==    by 0x400C7C: main (in /homes/iws/kieruc/Coding/a.out)
==45919==  Block was alloc'd at
==45919==    at 0x4C2A1E3: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:334)
==45919==    by 0x4EF3A18: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==45919==    by 0x400FFE: char* std::string::_S_construct<char*>(char*, char*, std::allocator<char> const&, std::forward_iterator_tag) (in /homes/iws/kieruc/Coding/a.out)
==45919==    by 0x400F14: char* std::string::_S_construct_aux<char*>(char*, char*, std::allocator<char> const&, std::__false_type) (in /homes/iws/kieruc/Coding/a.out)
==45919==    by 0x400EDD: char* std::string::_S_construct<char*>(char*, char*, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /homes/iws/kieruc/Coding/a.out)
==45919==    by 0x400E8F: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char*>(char*, char*, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /homes/iws/kieruc/Coding/a.out)
==45919==    by 0x400E20: std::string __gnu_cxx::__to_xstring<std::string, char>(int (*)(char*, unsigned long, char const*, __va_list_tag*), unsigned long, char const*, ...) (in /homes/iws/kieruc/Coding/a.out)
==45919==    by 0x400CDE: std::to_string(int) (in /homes/iws/kieruc/Coding/a.out)
==45919==    by 0x400C60: main (in /homes/iws/kieruc/Coding/a.out)
==45919== 
==45919== Invalid read of size 1
==45919==    at 0x573BACA: getaddrinfo (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==45919==    by 0x400C95: main (in /homes/iws/kieruc/Coding/a.out)
==45919==  Address 0x5a22058 is 24 bytes inside a block of size 29 free'd
==45919==    at 0x4C2B16D: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:576)
==45919==    by 0x4EF3B62: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==45919==    by 0x400C7C: main (in /homes/iws/kieruc/Coding/a.out)
==45919==  Block was alloc'd at
==45919==    at 0x4C2A1E3: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:334)
==45919==    by 0x4EF3A18: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==45919==    by 0x400FFE: char* std::string::_S_construct<char*>(char*, char*, std::allocator<char> const&, std::forward_iterator_tag) (in /homes/iws/kieruc/Coding/a.out)
==45919==    by 0x400F14: char* std::string::_S_construct_aux<char*>(char*, char*, std::allocator<char> const&, std::__false_type) (in /homes/iws/kieruc/Coding/a.out)
==45919==    by 0x400EDD: char* std::string::_S_construct<char*>(char*, char*, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /homes/iws/kieruc/Coding/a.out)
==45919==    by 0x400E8F: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char*>(char*, char*, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /homes/iws/kieruc/Coding/a.out)
==45919==    by 0x400E20: std::string __gnu_cxx::__to_xstring<std::string, char>(int (*)(char*, unsigned long, char const*, __va_list_tag*), unsigned long, char const*, ...) (in /homes/iws/kieruc/Coding/a.out)
==45919==    by 0x400CDE: std::to_string(int) (in /homes/iws/kieruc/Coding/a.out)
==45919==    by 0x400C60: main (in /homes/iws/kieruc/Coding/a.out)
```

However if I change the code to this

```
std::string portstr = std::to_string(port);

struct addrinfo *result;
int res = getaddrinfo(nullptr, portstr.c_str(), &hints, &result);
```

Then there are no memory errors. And I dont quite understand why.

Another thing to note is that if I try to compile the version with the `const char*` variable with `char*` instead you get a warning that the variable should be constant.

What is going on here?

Comment: I +1 'ed you for providing a (almost-)minimal, complete, verifiable example and also trying things out on your own. If only all newbie users did that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The buffer returned by `c_str` is valid only as long as the associated `std::string` object lives. And here

```
const char* port_num = (std::to_string(port)).c_str();
```

A **temporary** string object is created, its buffer address is taken, and then it dies at the end of the full expression. You get a memory error for using a dangling pointer.

If you wish to use a temporary `std::string`, it must be created during the full expression where you use the buffer:

```
int res = getaddrinfo(nullptr, std::to_string(port).c_str(), &hints, &result)
```

Comment: I like Stephan Lechner's suggestion better, since my coding philosophy (and what I teach people) is : Do one thing per line unless otherwise necessary. It doesn't change the compiled output and it's easier to read IMHO. One could argue it is more procedural and less functional, but that's [not necessarily true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14943681/scheme-let-statement).

Comment: @einpoklum - Another philosophy is to not name unimportant and transient things. And the "one thing per line" approach fails pretty fast in any C++ program. Taking the address of `hints` and `result` is also not inline with it. Most people, including myself, do something in between and for good reason. Anyway, this is neither here nor there. The point I was trying to clarify is the lifetime issues, no more.

Comment: I did say "unless otherwise necessary" - and it's often necessary, especially in C++... you do have a point about naming transients, but: 1. It's not bad to name what will soon become function arguments using the parameter name, seeing how C/C++ functions aren't invoked with named parameter assignments. 2. Transients are used right after they're named, so you can easily forget the name 3. Better to err on the side of being overly verbose than being cryptic. 4. With time I've found more things than I had expected can be given reasonable names.

Answer (score 4):

With `const char* port_num = (std::to_string(port)).c_str();`, you are creating a temporary object of type `std::string`, which will live just as long as the expression in which it is used. So the `.c_str()` will point to memory that will get freed right after your statement.

Make two lines out of it:

```
auto portStr = std::to_string(port);
const char* port_num = portStr.c_str();
```

Thereby, the `portStr`-object will live until the end of the function, and you may use the result of the `.c_str`-call right until the end of the function (unless you alter `protStr` in between).